# Delete data from sql database not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql

when you select items from the listbox, you want to delete selecteditems. Why doesnt it work when selected data removed from database? I must have missed something. I got error message
**No mapping exists from object type.**

This is a method parameter:

```
  IsDelete = _dinnerRemover.RemoveDinners(lstDinner.SelectedItems);
```

This class is to delete data from database

```
public bool RemoveDinners(dynamic dinnerItems)
{
    Dinners = new List<FoodInformation>();
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
    {

        const string sqlQuery = "delete from DinnerTemplates where Dinner = @dinner";

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
        {
            try
            {
                //command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //command.CommandText = "sp_dinner";
                foreach (var item in dinnerItems)
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dinner", item);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return Dinners;
}
```

Comment: no it is not string. parameter is dynamic type. what is data type parameter for listbox.selectedItems?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is and it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code you posted.

Comment: see if inserting the exact string to delete works.  Or adding .ToString()

Comment: listbox.selectedItems are string type.

Comment: i just edited my post. Look at the parameter. I have tried List<string> for the parameter. it doesnt work

Comment: yes i did put string. it doenst work because it is a list, not one string. I have tried List<string> parameter for listbox.selecteditems - not match data type

Comment: Your ListItem objects class needs an implementation of ToString. Also, where is SqlDbType set for @dinner. What exception is thrown?

Comment: how to implement listItems with ToString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dinnerItems` is a list of strings then say that, don't use `dynamic` unless you absolutely have to.

To delete a bunch of items, issue one sql query with an `IN` clause. Don't issue lots of individual queries.

Try this:

```
    public int RemoveDinners(List<string> dinnerItems)
    {
        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
        {

            const string sqlQuery = "delete from DinnerTemplates where Dinner in ({0})";

            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {

                var paramNames = new string[dinnerItems.Count];

                int i = 0;
                foreach (string item in dinnerItems)
                {
                    string paramName = "@Dinner" + i;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, item);
                    paramNames[i] = paramName;
                    i += 1;
                }

                command.CommandText = String.Format(sqlQuery, String.Join(",", paramNames));
                command.Connection = sqlConn;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                sqlConn.Open();

                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow it is working like a bomb. Thank you very very much! I am gonna mark answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bear in mind that you kind of left out some really relevant code, like what is a `DinnerItem`, since you're getting the error on a line related to its type.

However, the reason you're getting that error is because `item` can't be marshaled to a type of something like `string` or `int`.

That's probably because `item` is likely a custom class. One option would be to override the `ToString` method of the class:

```
public override string ToString() {
    // return some property value, or set of property values
    // strung together here.
}
```

another option would be to send in the actual `Property` you want off of `item` when issuing `AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define SqlDbType for command's parameter.

Answer (score 0):

don't use dynamic type,use string..
if i were you,i would rather

```
IsDelete = _dinnerRemover.RemoveDinners(lstDinner.SelectedItems.ToString());
```

change the parameter to :

```
public bool RemoveDinners(string dinnerItems)
```

and the query to :

```
const string sqlQuery = "delete from DinnerTemplates where Dinner = dinnerItems";
```